# Google Text-to-speech - Loading text from individual lines of a txt file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I am using the Google TextToSpeech API in Node.js to generate speech from text. I was able to get an output file with the same name as the text that is generated for the speech. However, I need to tweak this a bit. I wish I could generate multiple files at the same time. The point is that I have, for example, 5 words (or sentences) to generate, e.g. cat, dog, house, sky, sun. I would like to generate them each to a separate file: cat.wav, dog.wav, etc.

I also want the application to be able to read these words from the * .txt file (each word/sentence on a separate line of the * .txt file).

Is there such a possibility? Below I am pasting the * .js file code and the * .json file code that I am using.

*.js

```
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const projectId = 'forward-dream-295509'
const keyFilename = 'myauth.json'
const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient({ projectId, keyFilename });
const YourSetting = fs.readFileSync('setting.json');
async function Text2Speech(YourSetting) {
  const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(JSON.parse(YourSetting));
  const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
  await writeFile(JSON.parse(YourSetting).input.text + '.wav', response.audioContent, 'binary');
  console.log(`Audio content written to file: ${JSON.parse(YourSetting).input.text}`);
}
Text2Speech(YourSetting);
```

*.json

```
{
  "audioConfig": {
    "audioEncoding": "LINEAR16",
    "pitch": -2,
    "speakingRate": 1
  },
  "input": {
    "text": "Text to Speech" 
  },
  "voice": {
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "name": "en-US-Wavenet-D"
  }
}
```

I'm not very good at programming. I found a tutorial on google on how to do this and slightly modified it so that the name of the saved file was the same as the generated text.

I would be very grateful for your help.
Arek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go - I haven't tested it, but this should show how to read a text file, split into each line, then run tts over it with a set concurrency. It uses the p-any and filenamify npm packages which you'll need to add to your project. Note that google may have API throttling or rate limits that I didn't take into account here - may consider using p-throttle library if that's a concern.

```js
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-map
const pMap = require('p-map');

// https://github.com/sindresorhus/filenamify
const filenamify = require('filenamify');


const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const projectId = 'forward-dream-295509'
const keyFilename = 'myauth.json'
const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient({ projectId, keyFilename });
const rawSettings = fs.readFileSync('setting.json', { encoding: 'utf8'});

// base data for all requests (voice, etc)
const yourSetting = JSON.parse(rawSettings);

// where wav files will be put
const outputDirectory = '.';

async function Text2Speech(text, outputPath) {
    // include the settings in settings.json, but change text input
    const request = {
        ...yourSetting,
        input: { text }
    };
    const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);

    await fs.promises.writeFile(outputPath, response.audioContent, 'binary');
    console.log(`Audio content written to file: ${text} = ${outputPath}`);
    // not really necessary, but you could return something if you wanted to
    return response;
}

// process a line of text - write to file and report result (success/error)
async function processLine(text, index) {
    // create output path based on text input (use library to ensure it's filename safe)
    const outputPath = path.join(outputDirectory, filenamify(text) + '.wav');
    const result = {
        text,
        lineNumber: index,
        path: outputPath,
        isSuccess: null,
        error: null
    };
    try {
        const response = await Text2Speech(text, outputPath);
        result.isSuccess = true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.warn(`Failed: ${text}`, error);
        result.isSuccess = false;
        result.error = error;
    }
    return result;
}

async function processInputFile(filepath, concurrency = 3) {
    const rawText = fs.readFileSync(filepath, { encoding: 'utf8'});
    const lines = rawText
        // split into one item per line
        .split(/[\r\n]+/)
        // remove surrounding whitespace
        .map(s => s.trim())
        // remove empty lines
        .filter(Boolean);
    
    const results = await pMap(lines, processLine, { concurrency });
    console.log('Done!');
    console.table(results);
}

// create sample text file
const sampleText = `Hello World
cat
dog
another line of text`;
fs.writeFileSync('./my-text-lines.txt', sampleText);

// process each line in the text file, 3 at a time
processInputFile('./my-text-lines.txt', 3);
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I am trying to run it but I do receive an error. Debug Console says: Uncaught Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: c:\Users\...\node_modules\p-map\index.js
I installed both packages.

Comment: The march of forward progress...latest version is [ESM only](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-map/releases/tag/v5.0.0). Remove the package (`npm uninstall p-map`) then install the older version (`npm install p-map@4`) instead.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. Anyway another trouble: 
Failed: dog [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\AAA\Desktop\t3s\UsersAAADesktop 3s\dog.wav'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\AAA\\Desktop\\t3s\\UsersAAADesktop\t3s\\dog.wav'
}

Comment: don't forget to escape your slashes (`\ ` ), or just use unix style (`/`) instead - looks like `UsersAAADesktop` should be `Users\\AAADesktop`. Anyways, that's not related to this code - you're on to new problems. Good luck!